# DotNetNuke - Content Scheduling

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

Do you know of a module that let you publish content (via HTML PRO module or whatever) on a certain time and date? (example: 1.3.2011 at 2:43pm)

I know that there is a built in option for content scheduling by date, not by time.

I know you can do it with the Announcements Module. (But you can't format the output so I can't use it..)

Ideally, this module will support content-workflow and versioning (like the HTML Pro Module)

Comment: Maybe this isnt a concern for you but also need to think of the time zone - 2:43 your time may be 5:43 for someone else

Doesnt always matter but of great concern for some people.

Answer (score 0):

possibly News articles Ventrian systems
http://www.ventrian.com/Products/Modules/NewsArticles.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify the output of the Announcement Module. [Here](http://www.ralphwilliams.com/home/entryid/47/turn-dnn-announcements-module-into-a-jquery-slider.aspx) is an article about turning it into a Slider using  jQuery.